# How to add python path to CLion

Tags: python, c++, path, clion

I want to use matplotlib-cpp in my C++ project with CLion IDE.
My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(myProject main.cpp Vehicle.cpp Vehicle.h Simulation.cpp Simulation.h Point.cpp Point.h)

add_subdirectory(matplotlib-cpp-master)
target_link_libraries(myProject  matplotlib_cpp)
```

and I receive a error:

```
Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Python3_LIBRARIES
  Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS Interpreter Development Development.Module
  Development.Embed)
```

in this line in the matplotlib-cpp code

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
```

I tried to add my python installation to File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Python Interpreter. I also added python 3.10 to my W10 path variables.

Can somebody help me? I also read most of the related Stackoverflow questions, but they did not  work since im on Windows and dont use a cmake command.
I probably just have to add the path, but I dont know how.